# How to decrypt HTTPS traffic with tshark when I have the .key and .crt file?

Tags: openssl, wireshark, tshark

I have my domain .key and .crt file.

the key file include "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----"

when i use command on centos:

```
tshark -r /tmp/xx.pcap -o 'ssl.keys_list:any,443,http,/tmp/private.key' -o 'ssl.debug_file:/tmp/ssl.log' -Y http
```

the command output just HTTP traffic,can not decrypt HTTPS.

check the ssl.log:

```
    Wireshark SSL debug log 
    Private key imported: KeyID 
    6f:ab:57:6b:de:21:e6:e8:97:f7:2c:d6:e0:5a:7d:34:...
    ssl_load_key: swapping p and q parameters and recomputing u
    ssl_init IPv4 addr 'any' (0.0.0.0) port '443' filename 
    '/tmp/private.key' password(only for p12 file) ''
    ssl_init private key file /tmp/private.key successfully loaded.
    association_add TCP port 443 protocol http handle 0x5601fa093e00
    Private key imported: KeyID 
    6f:ab:57:6b:de:21:e6:e8:97:f7:2c:d6:e0:5a:7d:34:...
    ssl_load_key: swapping p and q parameters and recomputing u
    ssl_init IPv6 addr 'any' (::) port '443' filename 
    '/tmp/private.key' password(only for p12 file) ''
    ssl_init private key file /tmp/private.key successfully loaded.
    association_add TCP port 443 protocol http handle 0x5601fa093e00

    dissect_ssl enter frame #3 (first time)
    ssl_session_init: initializing ptr 0x7f295c88a7b8 size 696
    conversation = 0x7f295c88a490, ssl_session = 0x7f295c88a7b8
    record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 116
    dissect_ssl3_record found version 0x0303(TLS 1.2) -> state 0x10
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 23 Application Data
    decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 111, ssl state 0x10
    association_find: TCP port 52945 found (nil)
    packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
    decrypt_ssl3_record: using client decoder
    decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
    association_find: TCP port 52945 found (nil)
    association_find: TCP port 443 found 0x5601fab91df0
```

thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to Security SE. When you run the command, what happens? Do you get an error? If so, can you please include the error in your post by [editing](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/258069/edit) it in?

Comment: @nobody I've updated post,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recorded traffic can be decrypted using the end entity (leaf) certificate's private key only when the deprecated "RSA key exchange" was used. This key exchange has been deprecated for a long time and it is simply impossible in TLS 1.3. Exactly because of this property, that recorded traffic can be decrypted using the certificate's private key even after the certificate is revoked and/or expired, this was always considered a bad idea.

The property of not having this weakness is called "[forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy)" or "Perfect Forward Secrecy". It is achieved by using an ephemeral [Diffie Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) instead, and authenticating the anonymous Diffie Hellman key exchange using digital signatures using the key of the certificate (so RSA signature instead of RSA encryption, or ECDSA signature for ECDSA certificates). These days, we use Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman.

In short, `tls_rsa_with_aes_128_gcm_sha256` is bad, `tls_ecdhe_rsa_with_aes_128_gcm_sha256` is good. In the olden times, `tls_dhe_rsa_with_aes_128_cbc_sha` was the "good" cipher suite.

To decrypt the recorded traffic if a DHE or ECDHE key exchange was used, you need the DH private key of either side. The DH is ephemeral, meaning a new DH key pair is used for every connection, and it is immediately discarded after the handshake. Without the [SSLKEYLOGFILE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Key_Log_Format) file produced by either side of the communication exporting the keys, you cannot decrypt the traffic.